# How to show and hide an image properly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, css

I've been having issues trying to show and hide images inside of my ajax request function. In order to be clear of what I'm trying to do, I make a video less than 1 minute [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBvk8lXLezA&feature=youtu.be). If you see in the web console, there's a variable that is changing from "ocupado" to "libre" and that means if there's a free or busy parking space. So It kind of work because in the beginning my variable `"data" = ocupado` shows a car image, then when it changes to `"data" = libre` hide the car image. The problem starts when it changes again to `"data" = ocupado`because It doesn't show any car image.

Here's my code for ajax function

```js
<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function(){
  $("img").error(function () {
    $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "");
  });
  $(function ()
  {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'api.php',
      data: "",
      success: function(data)
      {
          console.log(data);
          if (data === "libre"){
          $("#slave1free").hide();
          $("#slave1busy").hide();

          }else{
          $("slave1free").show();
          $("slave1busy").show();  
          }
        }
      });
    })
  }, 1000);
```

```html
    <div class="chart">
      <div class="chartimage"><img src="images/parkinglot.jpg"></div>
      <div class="image" id = "esclavo1">
        <div class "free" id = "slave1free"><img src="images/carfree.png"></div>qQ
        <div class "busy" id = "slave1busy"><img src="images/carbusy.png"></div>
      </div>
```

By the way, carfree.png and carbusy.png are those images that are shown in the video next to "estacionamiento libre" and "estacionamiento ocupado". I put one image in top of the other because I was planning to show and hide both images according to value of data ("libre" or "ocupado").

Edit: Yes, I'm hidding both and showing both on purpose because I wanted to see where's the problem. Despite that both are showing or hidding at the same time, It would appear both images(one in top of the other) when `"data"=ocupado` ?

Comment: note that you are hiding the two items, or showing them at the same time... shouldn't be one of each?

Comment: Yup, you are hiding free and busy at the same time, or showing them at the same time. One should always be unhidden and one hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that you are hiding the two items, or showing them at the same time... shouldn't be one of each?

```
if (data === "libre") {
   $("#slave1free").show();
   $("#slave1busy").hide();
} else{
   $("slave1free").hide();
   $("slave1busy").show();  
}
```

-edit-

Just realized that you are missing the id selector ( # )  on the else

```
if (data === "libre") {
   $("#slave1free").show();
   $("#slave1busy").hide();
} else{
   $("#slave1free").hide();
   $("#slave1busy").show();  
}
```

Comment: Yes sure that should be my final code but currently, following my code it should appear both images when "data" = ocupado. I did in purpose because I believe my else syntax is not working at all.... any suggestions?

Comment: @JeancarloC. Whether you want to hide both or just one, you forgot the [id jquery selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) `$('#slave1free')` and `$('#slave1busy')` in your else condition.

Comment: @tektiv Yep, a simple error that hold me like 3 or 4 hours at least. Thanks for answering :) !

Comment: If this helped you, perhaps you want to accept the answer and move on.. :P

Comment: @JeancarloC. No problem ! Don't forget to mark Toni's answer as accepted since he answered your question :)